# Dbeaver, python. Обновление таблиц

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, dbeaver

После добавления строк в табличку PostgreSql в DBeaverе надо нажимать значок "обновить", чтобы записи добавились при просмотре. Можно это сделать как-то через python? Использую psycopg2. Коннекшн commit() и close() после добавления записей делаю.